# Mysql Date Issue With Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I just want to know how to check this date

[image]

to this date `2012-03-07` with where clause

Here is my Sql Query

```
SELECT u.`last_activity` FROM users u WHERE = '2012-03-07'
```

Response

> Null Response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT u.`last_activity` 
FROM users u 
WHERE DATE(u.`last_activity`) = '2012-03-07'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT u.`last_activity` 
FROM users u 
WHERE DATE(u.`last_activity`) = '2012-03-07'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is invalid and it also looks like last activity is a timestamp so your comparison won't work unless the timestamp is midnight.

Try this which works for all times within that date:

```
SELECT u.`last_activity` FROM users u WHERE last_activity >= '2012-03-07' AND last_activity < '2012-03-08'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this....

```
SELECT u.last_activity FROM users u WHERE STR_TO_DATE(u.`last_activity`,"%Y-%m-%d")= '2012-03-07';
```

Comment: you are adding extra function that could affect the speed of the query. You can't notice it when you are dealing with small databases but for large database you can. Why formatting when you can use `DATE` function? :)

Comment: I know this is not a good practice for huge database and i already  got my answer from your experience, i am so much confusion  about these two function